# tangent space of the manifold $\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold, tangent-spaces

The space of smooth, periodic, immersed curves
$$\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)=\{c \in C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d) : c'(\theta) \neq 0, \forall \theta \in S^1\}$$
forms an infinite-dimensional manifold. Supposedly the tangent space is the modelling space itself, i.e. $T_c\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)=C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d).$ I understand why $T_c\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d) \subset C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)$, but I don't see why we get the reverse inclusion because surely the trivial curve $\gamma(x)=0$ is in $C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d),$ but it cant be in $T_c\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)$ by definition of $\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)$. What am I missing?

Comment: Every vector space has zero, thus, your trivial curve trivially belongs to the tangent space.

Comment: @ Moishe Yes, I guess I was thinking of them just as sets. So why is it not weird that $T_c\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R^d})$ contains elements that are not derivatives of curves from $\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R^d})$? I thought that is precisely what the tangent space was in this case.

Comment: Think of a general 1-parameter smooth family of immersions $f_t(s), s\in S^1$, $t\in [0,1]$, i.e. a curve in $Imm(S^1,R^n)$ where $t$ is the parameter of the curve. Now, differentiate with respect to $t$ and see what you get. It is not the same as differentiating with respect to $s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the non-technical answer to your question is that the subset $Imm(S^1,\mathbb R^d)\subset C^{\infty}(S^1,\mathbb R^d)$ is open. Similarly to the finite dimensional situation the tangent spaces to an open subset is the modelling vector space. Otherwise put, for $c\in Imm(S^1,\mathbb R^d)$, $f\in C^{\infty}(S^1,\mathbb R^d)$ and $t\in\mathbb R$, you get $c+tf\in Imm(S^1,\mathbb R^d)$ is $t$ is suffieciently small. Thus you get a curve emanating from $c$ in direction $f$, and hence $f$ should be in the tangent space at $c$.

Comment: Thanks. I have some naive follow up questions. 1) Why does it matter if $t$ is sufficiently small? It seems to me that $c+tf$ is always in $\operatorname{Imm}(S^1,\mathbb{R}^d)$. 2) Is $f$ is in the tangent space at $c$ because $\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}(c+tf)=f$?

Comment: For question 2), the answer is yes. For 1), take $f$ to be $-c$ and $t=1$.  Indeed, for any $g\in C^\infty$ you can look at $c+t(g-c)$ to get a curve which equals $g$ at $t=1$.